# Finding unkonwn values in a matrices multiplication.

Tags: matrices

I have an unknown 3x3 matrix multiplied by a known 3x1 matrix. I also know the resulting matrix .
How would you go by solving for the values, or possible values, in the unknown matrix.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
A & B & C  \\
D & E & F \\
G & H & I  \end{array} \right)$
$\left( \begin{array}{c}
10   \\
11 \\
12  \end{array} \right)$ =
$\left( \begin{array}{c}
68  \\
167 \\
266 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: did you tried the multiplication? you get $3$ equations with $9$ variables. or more precise to say that you get $3$ sets of $1$ equation in $3$ variables.

Comment: Yes @OfirSchnabel , in this case A=1, B=2 ,C=3 ,D=4,...I=9

Comment: I believe there are more solutions.....

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this is meant not as a mathematical equation but as a puzzle, in which the letters are meant to stand for distinct digits. If so, it seems you've already given the solution in a comment. If you hadn't, you could find it by determining the $6$-dimensional solution space of the problem, considered as a mathematical equation (over the real numbers), and then some trial and error would probably suffice to find a solution in that space that lets the variables take on distinct one-digit integer values.